# Question about Past Perfect

Tags: grammar

Help me please to understand is it correct to use Past Perfect in this sentence:

> "(I met him 2 weeks ago). It seemed that he hadn't changed a lot".

"It seemed" refers to past tense, so it is appropriate to use Past Perfect.

Am I right, what do you think?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is correct.

In other words, this sentence means: *at the time when you met him 2 weeks ago, it seemed to you that he wasn't very different from what he had been like e.g. last year*. Because you're talking about a time earlier than the time when you met him, you need to use past perfect.